# how to find all indexes and their columns for tables, views and synonyms in oracle

Tags: oracle

I jotted down the following query which will list the index name and its columns for a particular table:

```
select 
b.uniqueness, a.index_name, a.table_name, a.column_name 
from all_ind_columns a, all_indexes b
where a.index_name=b.index_name 
and a.table_name = upper('table_name')
order by a.table_name, a.index_name, a.column_position;
```

I want to modify this so that if I pass in a `view` or `synonym` also it works. Our system has variations of views, synonyms so it will be really helpful to have one query to which i can just supply the name (be it view synonym or table) and it would spit out the indexes and their columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your query should work for synonyms as well as the tables. However, you seem to expect indexes on views where there are not. Maybe is it materialized views ?

Comment: I would assume he wants indexes from the dependent tables for a view

Comment: In that case, it could be tricky, but it needs to work with ALL_DEPENDENCIES and since a view can be based on an other view(s), it probably also needs a hierarchical query (CONNECT BY).

Answer (score 1):

> `SELECT *
>     FROM user_cons_columns
>    WHERE table_name = 'table_name';`