# Joining two tables in Oracle with different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, indexing

I'm trying to get the index_name, constraint_type and uniqueness of index based on the below query:

```
select constraint_name index_name, 
       'P', 
       'U' 
  from all_constraints 
 where owner = 'owner_name' 
   and table_name = 'table_name' 
   and constraint_type = 'P'
UNION
select index_name, 
       ' ', 
       substr(uniqueness,1,1) 
  from all_indexes
 where owner = 'owner_name' 
   and table_name = 'table_name'
   and index_name not in (
                          select constraint_name 
                            from all_constraints
                           where owner = 'owner_name' 
                             and table_name = 'table_name'
                          )
order by index_name
```

Now, I need to get the column_name corresponding to the index_name retrieved from the above query using the following queries:

If index is Primary (P):

```
select column_name
from all_cons_columns
where owner = 'owner_name' and constraint_name = 'index_name'
```

If index is not primary:

```
select column_name
from all_ind_columns
where index_owner = 'owner_name' and index_name = 'index_name'
```

Is there any way i can join the queries to get the column_name alongside each index_name? I need the duplicate entries for index_name if the index if built on multiple columns.

I've tried different joins but none seem to work in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018094/how-to-find-all-indexes-and-their-columns-for-tables-views-and-synonyms-in-orac.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you need.

```
> SELECT DECODE(PRIM
>              ,'P',(select column_name 
>                           from all_ind_columns 
>                          where index_owner = ta.owner and index_name= ta.index_name)
>              , (select column_name 
>                   from all_cons_columns
>                  where owner = ta.owner and constraint_name = ta.index_name) ), index_name from ( select constraint_name index_name,
>        'P' PRIM,
>        'U' UNIQ,
>        owner,
>        table_name   from all_constraints  where constraint_type = 'P'    and owner = 'OWNER_NAME'    and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' UNION select
> index_name,
>        ' ',
>        substr(uniqueness,1,1),
>        owner,
>        table_name   from all_indexes  where owner = 'OWNER_NAME'    and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
>     and index_name not in (
>                           select constraint_name
>                             from all_constraints
>                            where owner = 'OWNER_NAME'
>                              and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
>                           ) order by index_name ) TA
```