# How to tell if a DATE column in an Oracle table is indexed?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a 6B row table in a vendor's database that uses Oracle.

We are facing responsiveness issues. Any date queries we add turn our results from returning instantly to time outs after dozens of minutes. There are multiple date fields we might use. The vendor doesn't disclose which fields they have indexed.

Our access to the table is via JDBC making SQL queries.

The vendor does indicate we are accessing materialized tables rather than the views.

How might we determine which fields, particularly date fields, are indexed in the table?

---

If this question is the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018094/how-to-find-all-indexes-and-their-columns-for-tables-views-and-synonyms-in-orac) then there are several points of clarification needed. The question doesn't appear to be fully answered. That question's answer is that the OP's query should work - but none of the tables listed in their query appear in the the database we are looking. Our vendor system has dozens of databases and thousands of tables in each of the databases. Neither "ALL_IND_COLUMNS or ALL_INDEXES" is in that database.
Here is that question's query:

```
from all_ind_columns a, all_indexes b
```

Is this only for particular Oracle Databases? Is it found in a particular admin/meta database?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Oracle does not have `DATETIME` data types - it has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types; both of which have a time component.

Comment: You may also want to check if you're querying a real table, or a view.  If it's a view you may find that it's a calculated field and that you're getting a full table scan.  My first recommendation is to look at EXPLAIN PLAN, EXECUTION PLAN, AUTOTRACE, etc.  This will give you information such as which indexes are being used, etc.  https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan

Comment: Do you mean the database has no `ALL_IND_COLUMNS` or `ALL_INDEXES` views (which would be odd since they are standard Oracle views), or just that when you query them you get no results?

Answer (score 0):

If using Oracle SQL Devloper, right click the table and select Quick DDL > Save to worksheet

If using Toad, browse to the table, right click and select export DDL.

If using SQLPlus, there's a guide [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm)